# host the DNS dreamhost but the website somewhere else

Tags: dns, ip, dreamhost

I purchased domain on dreamhost. and I deploy my application on other server. How to connect the dreamhost domain to other server ip address?
In goddady, there is an option to specify ip address on other server.
but I can't find a those settings on dreamhost DNS.
Anybody has a similar experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. we need to set DNS only at the **Hosting** tab on

Dreamhost/websites/your_websites.

[image: custom Dns setting]

and Go to the **DNS** tab

[image]

First, click the **Refresh DNS**, it may take a few minutes

and then click the **Add Record** Button, and set your IP address on hosting.